# Run a bash file with python scripts automatically from a server

Tags: python, server, automation

I have a folder "Automation" that contains Python scripts which handle web automation tasks and extract text and Excel files. Those text and Excel files are temporary stored in "Automation".

Currently I am running the scripts 3 times a week from a bash wrapper file located in the same directory, but I would like that it **runs itself automatically** from a server so it's executed when I'm not using my computer.

How would you make this work? Thanks

Comment: Do you have `jenkines`? what operation system do you use?

Comment: Have you tried crontabs?

Comment: If its only time dependent - a cron job. More involved solutions (with more bells and whistles) are possible if there are other constraints as well - from using celery (http://www.celeryproject.org/) to writing your own systemd service.

Comment: I have never heard of Jenkins or crontabs (I'm a beginner) and I'm on MacOS

Comment: Try googling for setting up a cron job, thats prolly all you need.

Comment: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgSxYvFWjUY) is a video on cronjobs by Luke Smith. I believe he explains these things quite good. Good Luck.

Comment: Cronjobs work only when my computer is turned on right? What if I want it to run when it's off?

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to make a file that launches the bash file at specific times that you wish.I think that this script would help you:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
# the list below should be supplied with the times when you want to launch your bash script
times = [ "write times in the format(no whitespaces, only colons): day(lowercase):hour:minutes",  "day(lowercase):hour:minutes"]
path = r"Path/of/executable/bash/file"      # this is the bash file that runs your other python scripts
while(True):
    now=datetime.now()
    nowtime=now.strftime("%H:%M")
    today=now.strftime("%A")
    today=today.lower()
    time=today+":"+nowtime   # this line would bring it into the correct format

    for eachtime in times:      # These three lines would check if the current time is correct to launch the bash script
        if time = eachtime:
            os.system("cd "+path+"\r\n <command to execute bash>")      # If it is correct then execute the bash file.
```

You can start this script and let it run forever.. it would automatically launch the bash files at the correct times..

I hope i could solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

**(1) First you can put the following in file called** `wrapper.py`:

```
import time, sys

log, flush = sys.stdout.write, sys.stdout.flush

while True:
    log("I am waking up, let's run the scripts\n")

    # ****************************** #
    # call your python scripts here
    # example:
    # import script1, script2
    # script1.some_function1()
    # script2.some_function2()
    # ****************************** #


    log("Done for today, I will go to sleep for 1/3 a week (56 hours)\n")
    flush()

    #(60 seconds/minute)x(60 minutes/hour)x(24 hours/day) x 3 days = 259200 seconds
    hibernation = 259200 

    time.sleep(hibernation)  # sleep for 3 days = 259200 seconds
```

**(2) Then to launch this as a daemon, run this command in your terminal:**

`nohup python wrapper.py >> logfile.log 2>&1 &`

`nohup`
"no hangup", makes the python process continue running even after you close your terminal (or exit your shell)

`>>`
sends the output to a file named logfile.log

`2>&1`
sends both stdout and stderr to logfile.log

`&`
sends the running process to the background and gives shell control back to you

Notice you only run the `nohup` command once (unless the server restarts, then you you would have run it again. If this happens often, you can automate auto-restarting by putting the `nohup` command in an executable bash script, and then creating a `cron` job for example for that script).